# Can't change kernel.printk value

Tags: logs, console, sysctl, kernel-parameters

I want to set `kernel.printk` value to `5 4 1 1` for disable logging on booting but when I try

```
sysctl -w kernel.printk="5 4 1 1"
```

I get error:

```
sysctl: setting key "kernel.printk": Invalid argument
kernel.printk = 5 4 1 1
```

Also when I try write line

```
kernel.printk = 5       4       1       1
```

to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and run

```
sysctl -p
```

I have the same effect:

```
sysctl: setting key "kernel.printk": Invalid argument
kernel.printk = 5       4       1       1
```

What is wrong in my argument and how can I change it?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? What kernel version are you running?

Comment: You have to do that as root, not as a normal user.

Comment: @StephenKitt, Linux kernel version is 4.1.10

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I do it as root

Comment: @Shadasviar what distribution?

Comment: @StephenKitt, tizen

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk` ?

Comment: @WillCrawford, `5       4       1       5`, and it is not changing after my unsucceed action

Comment: Is `/proc` mounted, and are you certain you're running as root? [do double-check].

Comment: @WillCrawford, yes, absolutely

Comment: What happens if you try to set it to the same values it already has, and what happens if you write directly to it i.e. `echo "5 4 1 5" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` ?

Comment: @WillCrawford, if I try set the same value, the same error appears. `echo` cause `sh: echo: write error: invalid argument`